# WP Full Calendar not displaying Modern Tribe Events

Tags: fullcalendar

Quite new and a beginner with most of this but I can usually problem solve and follow along well enough to fix most minor errors although I'm having some trouble with this one. I'm building a WordPress site and using The Events Manager by Modern Tribe for a calendar because it has most of the functions I need. However, without paying for an upgrade there's no way to sort by category or display on another page other than the default hat it puts it on.  I was hoping to use WP Full Calendar to do both of these since it seems simple and really I just want the prior for fetching/creating the events not the calendar. Problem is WP Full Calendar isn't displaying any of the events although it is able to fetch the categories for them for use in sorting in the settings and seems to function properly aside form no events actually appear.

Wondering if anyone else has tried this and had similar hangups and it's something inherently about those two plugins that don't agree or if it's just me.

Comment: no obvious reason why it wouldn't just work. Presumably something in your faulty in the way you've used it. But without seeing the relevant code, it's impossible to say.

Comment: I also thought that might be the case and I've tried a few things to try to figure it out but no luck yet. I'm not sure about the code as I haven't written any for it; only using plugins without modifying them. I will see if I can get something for that here.

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing this very thing and the only option I found was to actually modify the plugin itself.  By default, fullcalendar expects dates from ACF or integration with Events Manager.  The fundamental problem is that Modern Tribe Events has it's own API for getting date information (like `tribe_get_start_date()` for the start date) and fullcalendar does not support it out of the box.